# Writing a batch file to delete a file after it appears?

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I want to write a batch file to delete a file when it appears after a weekly reboot of the system.  This is on a cctv system that the file appears and wont allow the system to run once this file appears.

Comment: You could use "if exist file_path del file_path", but you'd have to make it run every time your computer boots.

Comment: cctv = closed circuit TV? Wouldn't it be better to find out what is creating the file or what stops the system from functioning when the file is present, and fix that instead of just deleting the file whenever it is created? Perhaps there's a firmware update for the system? More details would be helpful -- make / model of CCTV system, name of file that it creates, where the files are being saved, how you delete the culprit file, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Several things need to be declared in this question first to actually make this work. Assuming you are using Windows 2000+, and that administrative privileges aren't required to delete the culprit file, then all you would have to do is open notepad and type the following:

Without the need of administrative privileges

```
@echo off
if exist "insert culprit file's path" del "insert culprit file's path"
```

With the need of an elevated batch/cmd prompt (administrative privileges to delete the file)

```
@echo off
CLS 
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  
ECHO. 
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation 
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
exit /B 

:gotPrivileges 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd
if exist "insert culprit file's path" del "insert culprit file's path"
```

Whichever one you need, put the code in notepad, and save the file as your.bat, and don't forget to go to where it says choose file type and select all files.